# Removing reference to BaseClass in Django Migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following models.

```
class ReservedSlug(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=80,
        unique=True,
    )

class SubClass(ReservedSlug):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
```

Now what happens in the database is that the SubClass has a foreign key relation to the ReservedSlug Base class of the following:

```
CONSTRAINT reservedslug_ptr_id_f48f6b16_fk_utils_reservedslug_id FOREIGN KEY (reservedslug_ptr_id)
    REFERENCES public.utils_reservedslug (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

And at the same time, it is setting the primary key to the following:

```
CONSTRAINT subclass_newsubclass_pkey PRIMARY KEY (reservedslug_ptr_id),
```

My goal is to remove the reference to Reserved slug all together and just have reservedslug_ptr_id be an IntegerField in SubClass model.

This is one of the ways I have tried inside the migrations:

```
database_operations = [ 
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name="subclass",
        name="reservedslug_ptr_id",
        field = models.ForeignKey('reservedslug_ptr_id', db_constraint=False, db_index=True, null=False)

    )

]

state_operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='subclass',
        name='reservedslug_ptr',
        field=models.IntegerField(db_index=True, null=False),
    )
]

operations = [
    migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
        database_operations=database_operations,
        state_operations=state_operations
```

And no matter what I do, I cannot get it to the way I want to get it. 
I keep getting this error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Auto-generated field
>   'reservedslug_ptr' in class 'SubClass' for parent_link to base class
>   'ReservedSlug' clashes with declared field of the same name.

I have been at this for the past 2 days, and just can't figure out what to do. I can't fully delete the field because I have other models referencing SubClass. 
My goal is to remove the reference to ReserveSlug while maintaining the primary key data in SubClass since the Foreign key is also the Primary key sadly! How can this be done in migrations? 
Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: It seems like what you want is an [Abstract Base Class Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). But is your question about how to do that or is it how to create the migration to take you from where you are now to having the slug field actually in the `SubClass` table?

Comment: I tried setting the ReservedSlug class to an abstract class but the problem is that it will remove the "reservedslug_ptr_id" which is a primary key of SubClass. And if I try to remove the primary key then I get a lot of errors. My question is what can I do in migrations to remove the reference to ReserveSlug while maintaining the primary key data in SubClass.  My goal is to remove Multi-inheritance.

Comment: can you add to the question, your new models definition do you want? and remove current migration to clear the question. Did you have any foreign keys to the `subclass`, i mean is it impossible to rebuild new value for primary key.